# 301 htaccess redirect from old path to new path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to the following redirect 301 to happen on `.htaccess` file for my site.

From:

```
 www.mysite.com/view/2133/page.html
```

To:

```
 www.mysite.com/node/2133
```

The `2133` will be a dynamic number like a * (eg `www.mysite.com/view/*/page.html`)so it will work for all my other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule view/([0-9+])  /node/$1  [R=301,L]
```

For an explanation see: [URL Aliasing, Redirection, Rewriting and Reverse Proxying using Apache HTTPD](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4043/URL-Aliasing-Redirection-Rewriting-and-Reverse-Proxying-using-Apache-HTTPD.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seems to work on my end.